# How to pause between functions in a program in C with GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, io, stdout, delay

So my problem is my program runs too fast that I can't see how it behaves. It's supposed to make the text crawl along the edges of the terminal. I tried to use `sleep()` to make a short pause between`printf(...)`s so that it I can see where the text us going while it prints.

This is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZMLJ.gif

So I put `sleep()` function after the `printf`s so that it will pause before starting the loop again and make the text move slowly. But what happens is it pauses the programs indefinitely before it even starts. This also happens with `usleep` and `system("pause 1")`. This is what it looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuquT.gif

==================================================================================

EDIT:

Okay, I figured it out on my own. It seems that `sleep()` only works if I put `\n` in my strings. I don't know why. I didn't even read this in the damn manuals.

So if you have

```
printf("HELLO\n");
sleep(3);
printf("HELLO\n");
sleep(3);
printf("HELLO\n");
```

It will result in:

`HELLO`

[pause for 3 seconds]

`HELLO`

[pause for 3 seconds]

`HELLO`

but if you remove the newline characters it will:

[pause for 9 seconds]
`HELLO HELLO HELLO`

I don't know why this happens but it just does

==================================================================================
EDIT:

This is how I wanted my program to work:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWZ8E.gif

Thank you for your answers

Comment: looks weird, try fflush(stdout) anyhow

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger (gdb)?

Comment: I-I'm a beginner, I don't even know how to use a debugger.

Comment: It is a good idea to learn it. Using a debugger will help you **a lot**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your observations do not due to `sleep()` not working, but to the fact that `printf()` uses `stdout`, which is line buffered. "line buffered" means, that what has been written to `stdout`is buffered until the end of the line is reached before the buffer's content it is flushed out.

So after the first `printf("HELLO");` the output does not go to the screen but stays in the buffer, then `sleep(1);` is executed and makes you wait. Then for the next `printf("HELLO");` the output still does not go to the screen, but the following  `sleep(1);` again makes you wait for 1 second ... and so on until a line end if reached by your program printing a `'\n'` or by the program's end, which implicitly flushes the output buffer to the console.

You can avoid the behaviour by flushing `stdout`'s output buffer explicitly after every `printf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("HELLO");
  fflush(stdout);
  sleep(3);
  printf("HELLO");
  fflush(stdout);
  sleep(3);
  printf("HELLO");
/* fflush(stdout); */ /* not needed as buffers are implicitly flushed on the program's end */

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I don't have to rewrite my whole program

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack I usually do is make some buffer array (eg. char buf[10]) and place an fgets() in between iterations, which forces the program to wait for a newline from the user.  So, for example, if we had:

```
.
.
.
for(i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

we could then do

```
.
.
.
char buf[10];
for(i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){
    printf("%d\n", i);
    fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
}
```

and control the iterations with the enter key.

We could also stop every nth iteration by using a modulus.  Using the above example, we will now stop every 100 iterations:

```
.
.
.
char buf[10];
for(i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i){
    printf("%d\n", i);
    if(i % 100 == 0)
        fgets(buf, 10, stdin);
}
```

A more time consuming but effecient way is to use a dedicated debugger like GDB.

Comment: I don't even understand your answer and I don't think it's even related to the question. :(

Comment: The function fgets() is an input function, which waits until a user gives the program some string, ended with the newline character.  In otherwords, it will wait until you press the enter key to continue the program.  By placing this function at the end of your while(1) loop, you can stop the program every time the loop runs, allowing you to view the output.

Comment: But that would mean my program won't run right? The finished product is supposed to be crawling text.

Comment: I apologize.  I assumed that you were trying to debug your program.  To slow it down for production code, you can use time.h to wait a specific length of time.  The second post of this link has an example in C++.  In C, the time structure that you want is equivalent to the C++ version.: (http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/78570-cplusplus-style-zelda-text.html#post555729)

Comment: That's C++ though. I know it works, but I still prefer purely C code

Comment: The time structure that you want is equivalent to the C version.  However, you should include <time.h> instead of <ctime>